# PackageReference version is ignored

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, csproj, packagereference

In our project we're creating different NuGet packages (using suffixes) for different branches. In the .csproj file I'm trying to specify the specific version of a package that should be used.
Package names can be `1.2.3`, `1.2.3-rc001`, or `1.2.3-pr001`.

**First issue:**
I tested using 
`<PackageReference Include="Package.Name" Version="[1.2.3,1.2.6)" />` where there was no 1.2.3. My understanding is it should use the next available version, but now it simply says the selected package is 1.2.3, with *"Not available in this source"*. Updating NuGets also ignores this and simply updates to the latest release, 1.2.10. After that it overwrites the Version in .csproj, so the specified bounds are lost.

**Second issue**, that falls in with the first, is to specify to only use -pr* or -rc* versions. `1.2.*-pr*` is not a valid option, so maybe our numbering scheme needs changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First issue: I tested using  where there was no 1.2.3. My understanding
> is it should use the next available version, but now it simply says
> the selected package is 1.2.3, with "Not available in this source".

**Actually**, when you set different versions of a nuget package by floating versions(in your situation, `1.2.3<=version<1.2.6`), **NuGet** chooses the package that's closest to the application and ignore the others. So it will choose `1.2.3` regardless of whether it exists in your current nuget caches.[See this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins).

So **PackageReference** will not reference the package based on the closest available version in your current cache and choose the newest version not matter whether it exits under your local machine.

> Second issue, that falls in with the first, is to specify to only use
> -pr* or -rc* versions. 1.2.*-pr* is not a valid option, so maybe our numbering scheme needs changing.

**At the moment**, prerelease versions cannot be used together with floating versions.It means that you cannot use any pre-release characters with floating versions . So `-pr*` and `-rc*` are illegal including `1.2.*-pr*`.

During use, no characters about the pre-release version can appear.

Instead, you can use

```
1.2.*-*
```

**Besides**, the `1.2.*-beta1` is also illegal. Though it shows a version under **Dependencies UI**, you can not find it under **Nuget Package Manager**-->**Installed** which means that the package is missing and the project has lost it.

**In addition**, there is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917703/how-to-include-pre-release-packages-with-msbuild-restore-target) which you can refer to.